# how to update value of a <td> using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a table displaying user's account details. In this table I am managing a user's account. Now i wish to display the updated value of accountStatus in the TD with class accountStatus.

```
foreach ($result_val->result() as $row) {
        $accountStatus = array('data' =>$row->accountStatus,'class' => 'accountStatus');
        $this->table->add_row($row->username,$row->email,$accountStatus,(($row->accountStatus == 'deleted')? " " :"<input  type=\"button\" id=".$row->userID." class=\"btn btn-warning btn-small block\" value=\"Block\"> <input type=\"button\" id=".$row->userID." class=\"btn btn-success btn-small activate\" value=\"Activate\"> <input type=\"button\" id=".$row->userID." class=\"btn btn-danger btn-small delete\" value=\"Delete\">"));
    }
```

when clicked on any of the button in the last table column the userID and new accountStatus value is send to the controller using

```
function manage_user_account(userID,value){
    $.post(url,{
        userID : userID,
        value : value
    },
    function(response){
        if(response.status == 1000){
            alert(response.accountStatus);
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.accountStatus').html(response.accountStatus);


            $("#headMsg").text('Account status has been successfully updated');
            $("#headMsg").show();
        }
        else if(response.status == 1300){
            $("#headMsg").text('Account status updation failed ! Try Again.');
            $("#headMsg").show();
        }
        else if(response.status == 1200){
            $("#headMsg").text('Web server error ! Try Again.');
            $("#headMsg").show();
        }
    },'json');
}
```

But the value is not updated at the same time, it is displayed after reloading the page.
Please help me with this.

Comment: is response.status something you are returning?

Comment: `this` does not refer to an element. What is it supposed to refer to?

Answer (score 0):

`this` is likely referring to the global window object.  Pass `event.target` from the click handler to your function:

```
$(foo).click(function(event) {
    ...
    manage_user_account(id,val,event.target);
}


function manage_user_account(userID,value,button){
...
    $(button).closest('tr').find('.accountStatus').html(response.accountStatus);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Because of your help I have got it done. It is working really well now.